Recover Staked Ada from Byron Wallet
Everything I read online states I was never able to stake ADA using a Byron era wallet. But I most certainly did back in 2021. Now, after installing Daedalus again, as that's all I ever used. I am confronted with needing to open a shelly wallet to utilize the staking.
https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/57a8f5bc4a2cdcb1a70d4b5aef04ea5953e8b3dbe9ecf77a7b14ea7d6599d8c7
I have only ever used Daedalus and no other wallet interface, why is it I cannot utilize the staking and unstake my ADA? Is this ADA just lost forever due to the Shelly upgrade?

Byron era accounts never supported staking. The staking functionality was introduced in the Shelley era. To restore your account, you should use the seed phrase (usually 24 words).

Looking at your stake-key history, your wallet is staked since Aug 21, 2021 and you have earned 47.179736 ADA in staking rewards during that time. As far as I know this means you upgraded your wallet to a Shelley wallet at some point.
https://cardanoscan.io/stakeKey/stake1u9qd5nzm4fyeky2vs4terdavyc30nudnx9u8x4uymrgp05chu4stx?tab=stakekeyhistory
The ADA is surely not lost. You could try to use the seed phrase (12 words) in another wallet and see if you can use the staking features there.
There are plenty of wallets to chose from. My personal favorite is Eternl where you can restore a 12 word Shelley wallet:

